# Velocity's resourceTool integration with Spring Framework

Tags: web-applications, spring-mvc, internationalization, velocity

hey guys,
I'm trying to integrate a resourceTool into spring.
it worked just fine,only 1 problem, default encoding was ISO-8859-1.
so..a bit of research and i came up with 3 possible solutions.

I. add a filter in web.xml :

 
  SetCharacterEncodingFilter
  org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
  
  encoding
  UTF-8
  
  
  forceEncoding
  true
  
 
 
  SetCharacterEncodingFilter
  /*

1. add a line in the viewresolvers:
2. manually changing the response's encoding:
   response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
   response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   (set encoding is just making sure as content type also sets the encoding itself)

HOWEVER, as soon as i've done EITHER of those, all my strings turn to gibrish, also no matter to what encoding i change it remains gibrish( only gets worse if anything).

any ideas on how to solve it?
anyone? ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You should probably tell Velocity to use UTF-8 also, with the input.encoding and/or output.encoding properties.